# How can I tell MyCountDownTimer to quit when the activity is not the current activity?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

The project i'm working on is an quiz with a timer on each question. for 30 seconds. I noticed that if you finish the test before the timer runs out, the timer doesn't stop running. So if you head on to another test, the notification that you haven't finished the test will popup and override the current activity. I tried using the cancel() method, but i'm sure I misplaced it.

Here is a snippet of the MyCountDownTimer Class

```
public MyCountDownTimer(TextView textCounter, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        this.textCounter = textCounter;
    }

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


  textCounter.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));

}

@Override
public void onFinish() {


    Intent retryIntent = new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), Retry.class);

       if (textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test1){
           whichTest = 1;
           retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
       }


    textCounter.getContext().startActivity(retryIntent);

}
```

This is a snippet of the Activity that implements the method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_page);

textCounter = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCounter));


    myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(textCounter, 29000, 1000);
    myCountDownTimer.start();
    textCounter.setText("");
    myCountDownTimer.onTick(29000);


}@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



if (questionIndex == questions7.length){

myCountDownTimer.cancel();

Intent intent1 = new Intent(Test1.this, UsersAnswers1.class);
            intent1.putExtra("usersAnswers1", usersAnswers1);
            intent1.putExtra("isATOF1", isATOF1);
            intent1.putExtra("score1S", score1S);
            startActivity(intent1);

}
}
```

Comment: looks like user is migrating to next activity on completing the quiz by pressing button and call to `onClick` comes ? Correct if I am wrong.
You can simply cancel the time here by calling cancel move to next activity, why you are explicitly calling `onFininsh`.

Comment: @Satty I accidentally left out some information. I edited the last block of code.

Comment: More doubt about problem, is it the Retry activity which comes or some pop up window then same activity. Your code looks fine. Are you doing something in onpause or onstop as onfinish of timer suggest Retry activity should open if timer is still active.

Comment: @Satty, The Retry activity pops up. As far as I know I didn't do anything to make it continue going.

Comment: In `onClick` you called onFinish on timer if textCounter is null. I can see only this part is calling retry activity, try removing this part check is it the cause ? If so please check why textCounter is null as when activity is running it should not get null.

Comment: I removed the **if (textCounter=null)** statement but the result is the same

Comment: `myCountDownTimer.onFinish();` this statement also removed ?

Comment: yes. I was playing around with the onCancel() method and apparently it wor when I don't need it to. Whenever I say if (questionNumber==10){myCountDownTimer.cancel();  } it stops. For some reason I can't find a condition that will cancel once the activity is over.

Comment: if you want timer to over once activity is over then cancel timer in `onStop` of activity

Comment: @Satty how do I do that when the last bit of code is the intent to start the next activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override onStop method of your activity and use code like

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    myCountDownTimer.cancel();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Hence whenever your activity goes in background it will cancel any timer associated with current activity.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But I noticed that unless I head back to my MainActivity, the timer still runs, i'll try putting it in the other Activities and see what happens.

Comment: Ok I realised that my other Activites were a subclass of the Activity with the timer so that must be why it continued running.

Comment: Another thing i reaised is that even if my other activities extends the Activity with the timer, all I had to do was place the cancel() method in the onCreate() of the new Activity.